# Function to increment and return a value (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets suppose I've a row with ID equals to 1 in table t.

If I run the following sql, I get a result equals to 1 (when column c is 0):

```
SELECT NEXT_ID(1)
```

But, if run this, I get 1 as a result, instead of 0 (as there is no row with ID = 2 in table t):

```
SELECT NEXT_ID(2)
```

NEXT_ID function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION NEXT_ID(id INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
 BEGIN
  DECLARE counter BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
  UPDATE t SET c = (@counter := c +1) WHERE ID = id;
  return @counter;
 END;
```

My intent here is to create a counter that increment a value as an atomic operation.
So, why do I get a value greater than 0 on NEXT_ID(2)? It seems like the counter variable is been stored in the session...

Is this safe to use in a multithreaded application?

Comment: @RaymondNijland, every row in table t has a column that act as a counter (or lastest id). This is why AUTO_INCREMENT doesn't work for me.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id  has a safe method of making a sequence search for `CREATE TABLE sequence (id INT NOT NULL);` in the document

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I think when using the `LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1)` trick, the update is still subject to transaction and locking semantics. So it's not good for concurrent throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `DECLARE counter` then you should NOT use `@counter` to refer to the variable. In a MySQL stored function, declared variables don't have the `@` sigil. Variables with the `@` sigil are [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). `@counter` is a different variable than `counter`, even though they have the same spelling.

Is it safe to do in a multi-threaded app? Certainly if the threads are incrementing different rows by using different `id` values, they will not conflict (assuming `id` is a unique key of the `t` table).

Even if multiple threads use the same `id` value, and therefore need to increment the same row in the `t` table, what will happen is that one will get there first, get a lock on the row, and increment it. The second thread will wait to get its own lock until the first thread commits its transaction. Then the second thread will proceed, and will then see the incremented value of `c`.

So it's safe, but it will not allow a high rate of throughput. Threads that are in contention for the same `id` will have to queue up and wait for the current holder of the lock to commit their transaction. If you're expecting multiple threads to do their work in parallel, you'll find this becomes a bottleneck.

This is why `AUTO_INCREMENT` exists, because it locks the counter briefly to generate a new value, but it releases the lock immediately, not waiting for the caller's transaction to finish. This allows concurrent threads to keep working and not wait for one another.

You can't simulate the behavior of `AUTO_INCREMENT` with `UPDATE` operations, which are necessarily in transactions.

---

Re your comments:

Sorry, I forgot that `:=` doesn't work with local declared variables. I tested it and I found two alternatives:

Alternative 1: don't bother to declare a local variable, just use the user-defined variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION NEXT_ID(id INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
READS SQL DATA
 BEGIN
  UPDATE t SET c = (@counter := c +1) WHERE ID = id;
  RETURN @counter;
 END
```

Alternative 2: use a local variable, but set the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to the incremented value. Then `SET` the counter local variable to that value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION NEXT_ID(id INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
READS SQL DATA
 BEGIN
  DECLARE counter BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
  UPDATE t SET c = LAST_INSERT_ID(c +1) WHERE ID = id;
  SET counter = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  RETURN counter;
 END;
```

I tested both alternatives and they work.

Comment: Bill, is there a way of setting counter (instead @counter as you stated) while executing my update? Like: UPDATE t SET c = (counter = c +1) WHERE ID = id;
I've tried but it doesn't seems to store the value on counter variable

Comment: Use `SET c = (counter := c + 1)` because `=` in that expression is a comparison operator, not assignment.

Comment: And make sure your `counter` variable doesn't have the same name as a column in that table, or it'll be ambiguous whether you mean the variable or the column of the same name.

Comment: it doesn't work. just "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= " always : /

Comment: Thank you for  your help!
do you think that using an user-defined variable or LAST_INSERT_ID are both thread safe?  Every row on table t has its own counter (column c), I'm just afraid of messing with those values when multiple updates are executed in parallel

Comment: User-defined variables are local to your session, so concurrent clients cannot read or change each others' variables. LAST_INSERT_ID() is explicitly meant for concurrent environments.